# retrieve excel data by each cell using oledb connection

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

i have a code for retrieve each data from excel to update dbf file. i use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for read the data each range of column.
now i want to change the connection excel using oledb..
how can i retrieve data of each column and set it into a variable?
here is my code for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

```
   xlApp = New Excel.Application

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsName)
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
            xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
            endrow = xlRange.Rows.Count

            For rCnt = 3 To endrow

                Empno = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 1).Value
                totalhrs = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 3).Value 
                latehr = xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 4).Value 

             Next

            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()
```

this is my oledb connection. after the connection,i really dont have an idea what should i do to get the data. please help me...i hope someone in stackoverflow can help me.

```
         Dim xlsConnect As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

  Try

        If (Path.GetExtension(xlsName) = ".xls") Then
            xlsConnect = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & xlsName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2""")
        ElseIf (Path.GetExtension(xlsName) = ".xlsx") Then
            xlsConnect = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & xlsName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';")
        End If
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", xlsConnect)
        'looping data should be here

        xlsConnect.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will display your details in a datagridview.You can try this piece of coding :

```
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()
```

If you want to use variables you have to loop through your dataset:

```
dim i as integer = 0
for i = 0 to dtset.tables(0).rows.count-1
'Add values to your variable
next
```